# What happens to the current fragment once popBackStack() is called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I have a fragment loaded, fragment A, and replace that fragment with fragment B, adding fragment A to the backstack like so:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment frag, String fragTag) {
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag, fragTag);
    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

and then from fragment B I call:

```
popBackStackImmediate();
```

So that fragment A is loaded again. What happens to fragment B? In my code I am creating a new Fragment B object and loading it with my replaceFragment() method, and repeating the process. Am I creating a bunch of fragment B's every time I replace A with B and call popBackStack() or is B destroyed when popBackStack is called? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`popBackStack()` reverses your last transaction, in your case, a `replace` transaction.

The FragmentTransaction docs are pretty clear about that. What replace does:

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is
>   essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently
>   added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then
>   add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

So, if A is added and you call `replace(container, B)`, you are actually calling

- `remove(A)`
- `add(B)`

That said, reversing this transaction with `popBackStack()` essentially does:

- `remove(B)`
- `add(A)`

Which instance of A or B, you ask, it depends on how you use your method. As far as I know, a `remove`d fragment will be destroyed (unless you keep a reference to it). If you call `new Fragment()` each time, than the answer is simple - you are creating lots of instances.

The `FragmentTransaction` API offers alternative ways to deal with situations like yours, in which you have to switch `A` and `B` more times. These are, again, well documented. For instance, you can use [`hide()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide(android.app.Fragment)) and [`show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show(android.app.Fragment)) to hide fragment A and show fragment B, without having A garbage collected and creating unnecessary new instances.

In addition, you could use [`detach()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach(android.app.Fragment)) and [`attach()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#attach(android.app.Fragment)). The difference with show and hide is that this way the **fragment views** (note: not the fragment **instances**) will be destroyed and recreated each time. Hide and show, on the other hand, just make the view invisible without destroying it.